# SQLite extension in VSCode not showing tables

Tags: database, sqlite, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, database-table

I am trying to use SQLite in VSCode. I have installed SQLite extension by Alexcvzz. after opening the database when I right-click on the table and select "Show Table" no data appear. please see the picture below.

**Note: I have created a database in SQLite, and the database has  data in it.**

[image: VSCode screenshot after clicking "Show Table"]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. I just noticed that Alexcvzz updated it on Nov 6th 2021. This was mentioned in the changelog. I've updated and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use **the other extension [**SQLite Viewer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qwtel.sqlite-viewer)** on **VSCode**.

By clicking on **SQLite database files**, you can see the tables and their data in **SQLite**.